# Accent Color IoT Core

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

Is there a way to set the system accent color on IoT Core? My MS account on all my x64 setups has a nice green and the default on IoT Core looks like a rather corporately somber cornflower blue (haha Fight Club) when I deploy to IoT Core from VS2017. Since IoT doesn't use my MS account and just uses a Default account, it doesn't retain my theme settings.

I can set it manually in my code for my specific app sure, but I'm wondering if it's possible to set the color system/user wide. I'm on the release not insider preview version due to crashes and other stability issues.

Here is a photo to illustrate the issue.
The same code is running on both the top (Windows 10 Enterprise x64) and bottom left monitor (Windows IoT Core ARM) to control RGB light bulbs in my room. The top has my accent settings of green and the IoT Core version does not.

[image: UWP Accent Color Differences]

Comment: I am afraid you do need to set color in the app because it looks like no such theme settings in windows iot core for now. What we see in the display is an app UI not system things.

Comment: That's what I figured. I did a full registry search on HKLM/HKU from PowerShell for words like Accent and Color and came up with nothing useful.

Comment: I'm having an even stranger issue now that both of my 32GB U3 microSD cards are messing up on the RPI3 with Windows IoT Core (stable build and insider preview) are getting BSODs if I either change the device name (it always wants to default to minipcw even if I set it in the IoT Core Dashboard when flashing). Having this issue with AndroidTV for Pi too. Linux works fine on both cards though, but I can't get Linux to run my UWP apps (or even Xamarin APKs) obviously.

Comment: It's the government, they mess with my tech because they want me to run around with a little tin foil hat on. :P